# aligning text to a path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text-wrap

I want to align some text so it matches the curve of a face.

If you see the image below you can see the text and I have drawn a path that I want each line of text to go.  The effect will be that the text is not vertically aligned, each text line will go in to the drawn line that matches shape of face.

[image]

I hope I made that clear what I mean.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn a shape to a text area by selecting the shape layer and clicking on the path with the type tool.

Im not sure if the line you already have is a shape/path or not, but all you need to do is (with the pen tool) draw the shape to exactly how you want the text area to be. Select the type tool and click on the shape you just created. That will turn the shape to a text area you can use as you would any other text area.

Comment: Nope.. His question is different.  What you saying is,Text will be typed on the path we drawn. But his question is to align texts with particular area he mentioned.

Comment: No, I'm not saying type on a path, if you click on a closed shape with the type tool it will turn it to a text area not type on the path.

Comment: Cool man... that makes sense.... Its working...!!

Comment: I hope you can solve my problem too..... Have a look on this question if you are free...  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/how-to-save-multiple-smart-objects-as-seperate-image-files-in-a-single-click

Answer (score -1):

What I have understood so far from your question is, you are having trouble to align the text with the face curves.

Now, if you are using a single Text Layer to write all of the texts that you showed (please see the attached image)

[image: Problem guessed by me]

Then it would be difficult for you to align the text with the curve. Because, the Text Panel in Photoshop differs in a multiple way than that of Microsoft Word.

So, instead of using a Single Text layer, I suggest you to use multiple Text layers, if you want to align the texts with the facial curves. (please see the attached image)

[image: Solution based on the guessed problem]

Then, you can move the individual Text layers easily and using the Move Tool you can align the Text layers to your preferred points.

Combining the Shape & Text layers is another way of work. But, I guess, you are not looking to combine those two.

Comment: Yes, I can definitely do that. But, won't that be difficult for an user who is a Beginner in Photoshop?
An user may be at Beginner or Expert level. So, I just gave a suggestion starting with the Beginner level.