# How to save multiple smart objects as separate image files in a single click?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I downloaded a psd file from some website. In that , it had various smart object layers in a single image. When i hit save, these smart object layers are saved as separate image files.

I don't know whether you understand my question or not. If you didn't, then see the image below (for example)

[image]

Consider the above image, these four colors are four separate smart object layers. When i hit save, each layer will be saved as separate files. Like below !

[image]

> **So how can i do this....?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with the built in script 'Export Layers to Files'. Just go to `File -> Scripts -> Export Layers to Files`.

There is an option to trim layers, which will export each layer at a size that fits its content, or at the size of the original document if it's turned off.

As far as I'm aware you can't do this specifically for smart objects, but you can only export visible layers, so just make the smart objects the only visible layers before running the script if there are other layers you don't need to export.

Comment: Awesome man.... that worked... Lots of hidden features are there in photoshop which i didn't find still....

Comment: i got another doubt. What i should do if i want to save images(Layers) in different resolution in a single click by hitting save button. For example, i need to create a logo for my android application. For that i need the logo in different sizes. How can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in Photoshop Generator Tool. You can find it in `File > Generate > Image Assets.`

This will export every layer or layer group that has a filename on it (Ex: Layer0001.png, layer3.jpg).

Among the several options this tool provides is that you can even export both a group and all the layers inside or even export multiple files with different formats and resolutions out of the same layer.

It's a good option if you want it to be exported and updated in real time. You don't even need to go to the menus, it's just automatic.

You can learn more about this Generator tool here: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html